# How to change SVG text programmatically?

Tags: java, java-me, svg

It looks like there is no analog to JavaScript's

```
svgDocument.createTextNode("my text content");
```

Answer (score 2):

SVG is just a kind of XML, so you may use any of the zillions of XML APIS to manipulate it (perhaps starting with DOM)